# Run Blazor WebAssembly app without publishing and IDE

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

There are several Web apps (Razor Pages) and several backend services (Web APIs). They interact somehow with each other.

Usually, I want to debug one of them using IDE (Visual Studio), and the rest should be running as a separate processes without IDE.

I wrote a small GUI utility. It's a some sort of "shell". It can launch apps and services as a console apps, so it's easy to launch/stop app or service which I want to be running. In this case, I don't use publishing, and all works fine. In case of "regular" ASP .NET Core apps it's enough to pass `contentroot` to `dotnet.exe`, and it will bind `wwwroot` from project's source and files from project's `bin`:

```
dotnet YourApp.dll --urls http://+:1234 --contentroot ..\..\..\
```

Now I'm developing Blazor WASM app within the same bunch of apps/services.
I know, that from browser's point WASM app is just a set of static files.

But how to open it without IDE and publishing, like VS does?

I thought, I could write command in my "shell" to run browser with local URI like `file:///...`. But if I try to open `index.html` from wwwroot manually, this fails, because all Blazor stuff is in the app's `bin` folder.

Is there any way to do this, or publishing is required?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a webserver at least and set the Blazor-Environment header. Our wasm apps are served by nginx from a container.

Dockerfile based on basic nginx:

```
FROM nginx:alpine as runtime

COPY ./configure-environment.sh /docker-entrypoint.d/
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.d/configure-environment.sh

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ENV BLAZOR_ENVIRONMENT=Production
ENV PORT=8080

WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY /publish/wwwroot .
```

configure-environment.sh looks like:

```
sed -i -e 's/BLAZOR_ENVIRONMENT/'"${BLAZOR_ENVIRONMENT}"'/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
sed -i -e 's/PORT/'"${PORT}"'/g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And then the nginx config with types { wasm } and add-header and location /.

```
http {
    include mime.types;
    types {
        wasm;
    }
    server {
        listen PORT;
        index index.html;

        add_header Blazor-Environment BLAZOR_ENVIRONMENT;

        location / {
            root /home/site/wwwroot;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
    }
}
```

Copy all files from your app into the container and the browser knows what to do when accessing '/' from the nginx deployment.

Comment: As far as I understand, your way assumes that publishing has been done already?